# How to download a file from box using wget?

Tags: wget, box-api

I've created a direct link to a file in box:

[image]

The previous link is to the browser web interface, so I've then shared with a direct link:

[image]

However, if I download the file with a wget I receive garbage.

How can I download the file with wget?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The solution was to add the `-L` option to follow the HTTP redirect:

```
wget -v -O myfile.tgz -L https://ibm.box.com/shared/static/xxxxx.tgz
```

Comment: This just downloads an HTML file, not the  tgz file.

Comment: I agree with @DavidParks , this just downloaded an HTML file.

Answer (score 18):

I was able to download the file by making the link public, then replacing /s/ in the url with /shared/static

So my final command was:

```sh
curl -L  https://MYUNI.box.com/shared/static/EXAMPLEtzwosac6pz --output myfile.zip
```

This can probably be modified for `wget`.

Comment: Note: This works for files/zipped directories, but not for directories (at least for me).

Comment: True, I would check out @eloqz below for a directory. I haven't tried that myself though

Answer (score 6):

I might be a bit late to the party, but FWIW:
I tried to do the same things in order to download a folder.
I went to the box UI and opened the browser's network tab on the developer tools.
Then I clicked on download and copied as cURL the first link generated, it was something like (removed many headers and options for readability)

```
curl 'https://app.box.com/index.php?folder_id=122215143745&rm=box_v2_zip_folder'
```

The response of this request is a json object containing a link for downloading the folder:

```
{
  "use_zpdl": "true",
  "result": "success",
  "download_url": <somg long url>,
  "progress_reporting_url": <some other url>
}
```

I then executed `wget -L <download_url>` and was able to download the file using wget

Answer (score -1):

What you can do in 2022 is something like this:

```
wget "https://your_university.app.box.com/index.php?rm=box_download_shared_file&vanity_name=your_private_name&file_id=f_your_file_id"
```

You can find this link in the POST method in an incognito under Google Chrome's network tab. Note that the double quotes escape characters.